# how to use boost for bessel function in C++

Tags: c++, boost, bessel-functions

I try to write spherical bessel function in C++ and use
 `#include <boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp>` and `sph_bessel(v,x)` in my code but error is happened say this not declared in this scope.I compile with g++ test.cpp .please help me.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // spot check for n == 1
    double x = 1.2345;
    cout << "j_1(" << x << ") = " << sph_bessel(1, x) << '\n';
}
```

compile the code with:

```
g++ test.cpp
```

and give this error:

```
 error: ‘sph_bessel’ was not declared in this scope
 cout << "j_1(" << x << ") = " << sph_bessel(1, x) << '\n';
 a.cpp:9:38: note: suggested alternative:
 In file included from a.cpp:3:0:
 /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp:544:79: note:            ‘boost::math::sph_bessel’
 ename detail::bessel_traits<T, T, policies::policy<> >::result_type     sph_bessel(unsigned v, T x)
```

Comment: You probably missed to specify the necessary namespace qualifier for `sph_bessel(v,x)`.

Comment: Please paste a simple version of Your cpp file, which when compiled shows this error. ALSO please paste the full error message generated by compiler for this simple version. In short, please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what to do:

```
 a.cpp:9:38: note: suggested alternative:
             ‘boost::math::sph_bessel’
```

so the code should be:

```
 cout << "j_1(" << x << ") = " << boost::math::sph_bessel(1, x) << '\n';
```

or You could add:

```
using namespace boost::math;
```

but this is strongly discouraged: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

So I would instead suggest:

```
namespace bmath = boost::math;
```

Then instead of `boost::math::sph_bessel(1, x)` You can write: `bmath::sph_bessel(1, x)`.

Comment: thank you.its work.now I want to change x from double to complex<double> and error happened again. do you know how to solve it?

Comment: With C++17, this function is available as a standard library:[std::sph_bessel, std::sph_besself, std::sph_bessell](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_math/sph_bessel)

Comment: It looks like complex might not be used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981747/why-wont-boosts-bessel-function-compile-with-a-complex-input